# In taffy.js how can I use use an object property name as a column name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object that looks like

```
{
  "rData": [{ 
    "cusName": "The CompanyLLC" 
  }]
}
```

I want to insert it into a taffy.js database, using the keyname `cusName` as the column name.

I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= json.rData.length - 1; i++) {
  var Name = Object.keys(json.rData[i])[0];
  console.log(Name)

  flagTaffy.insert({
    [Name]: json.rData[i][Name]
  });
}
```

The `console.log` correctly shows as `cusName` but in taffy, I get the index number of the record.

How do I get the keyName as the column name?

Comment: Why don't you just do `flagTaffy.insert(json.rData[i])`?

Comment: However, what you're doing looks like it should work. If you do `console.log({[Name]: json.rData[i][Name]})` do you see the expected object?

Comment: flagTaffy.insert(json.rData[i]) worked for my purposes. 
console.log({[Name]: json.rData[i][Name]}) displayed as expected. It's a mystery to me why the index was in the taffydb. 
If you want to post your answer as a solution I'll give you the credit. thanks

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer if I can't tell what's wrong. I think you must have mistyped something.